# How to detect which table was clicked with Jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have a page that contains multiple tables with unique id's that are populated with data from an ajax call. In the code below I am trying to figure out how to detect the closest table to which the button was clicked and only append new data to that table. I think this is possible with jquery's .closest() method but can't figure out how to do it? Here's a fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jsykes/cjs4ze8o/2/) Can anyone show me?

```
<table id="myTable1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Info</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Add data

```
<table id="myTable2">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Info</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Add data
The jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a').click(function() {
       $('#myTable1 > tbody > tr').append('<td>info,</td>');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other answers are correct also but here is another approach using unobstrusive way of doing it using a [data-attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) to tell which table to interact with:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a').click(function() {
    $("#" + $(this).data("table")).find('tbody > tr').append('<td>info,</td>');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" data-table="myTable1">Add data</a>
<table id="myTable1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Info</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<!----ANOTHE TABLE---->
<a href="javascript:void(0);" data-table="myTable2">Add data</a>
<table id="myTable2">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Info</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the relationship between the DOM elements. As `table` is immediately following sibling of `anchor` element, [`.next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next/) function can be used to target it.

```
$('a').click(function() {
   $(this).next('table').find('> tbody > tr').append('<td>info,</td>');
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/00s9xtve/)

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the table and the link in a div and then look inside.

```
$('a').click(function() {
   $(this).parent().find('table > tbody > tr').append('<td>info,</td>');
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xf7Lz982/)

With this approach it's not important if your button is above or under the `<table></table>` code.